My Pages Have Been Redirected Automatically in WordPress. How to Stop It?
I have published several pages and I noticed in Search Console that the page has been redirected to another URL.
No one worked on it. Is it possible for WordPress to do automatic redirections?
If yes, how can I fix that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, WordPress sometimes automatically redirects URLs under certain conditions when it detects changes in the permalink structure or slugs
Check Permalink Settings:
Go to Settings > Permalinks in your WordPress dashboard.
WordPress Redirect Rules in .htaccess file
Disable Plugins that Handle Redirects if any activated for WordPress dashboard
If you have checked WordPress Core and Theme Code for Redirect functions.php file or custom plugin wp_redirect() or redirect_canonical() functions
